# Proper use of the word "increasingly"

Tags: grammaticality

Decision making is an increasingly global challenge.
Is the word "increasingly a proper usage of the word?

Answer (score 1):

> Decision making is an increasingly global challenge.

Is grammatically correct.

Comment: I don't think the second example is correct at all. The first sentence says that the **challenge** of **decision making** is becoming more **global**. The second suggests that some aspect of the **global challenge** of **decision making** is increasing — without specifying *which* aspect that is.

Comment: Good point @PierceDarragh. Doesn't the second sentence states that **decision making** is a **global challenge** that is **increasing**?

Comment: Yes, but increasing *what*? It seems to me you're implying that the challenge is becoming more difficult, but I don't think that's an obvious parse from that sentence. I would prefer "Decision making is a global challenge of ever-increasing difficulty" to make it clear to the reader what is meant by "increasing". (I think this comes down to ambiguity, and I don't think the ambiguity is necessary. Therefore my solution is to write out the ambiguity altogether.)

Comment: Thanks @PierceDarragh, I just removed the second example with the ambiguity.

Comment: Appreciated! Have an upvote! :)